# OneSignal does not want to replace old notifications with a new one

Tags: php, push-notification, onesignal

I'm trying to send a notification using OneSignal. Everything is fine, but I need somehow to make sure that the new notification does not overwrite the older one. So if I send two notifications to the chrome on the android phone, so I get two notifications on the lockscreen and not just the new ones.

I searched for documentation and found the items "collapse_id" and "android_group" where I give values (string)microtime (true) and it did not help.

Here is a simple PHP posting notification.

```
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => $oneSignalID,
        'included_segments' => [ 'All' ],
        "headings" => [ "en" => "test heading" ],
        'contents' => [ "en" => 'test content' ],
        "collapse_id"=> "ff".(string)microtime(true),
        "android_group"=> "ff".(string)microtime(true),
        "url" => "http://www.example.com"
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization: Basic '.$onesignalkey
    ) );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
```

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1):

From OneSignal's staff:

You can stack notifications with OneSignal using our API and the steps below. We have disabled this from our dashboard due to misuse and complaints from customers.
When using our REST API to programmatically send notifications, you can use the undocumented parameter web_push_topic.

In a set of notifications sharing the same web_push_topic, newly received notifications will replace older received notifications with the same topic. Only notifications sharing the same topic will be replaced; notifications without a topic or with a different topic will not be replaced. You can set different topics for different sets of notifications to control which notifications stay on screen.

The web_push_topic value can be any string value.

On Chrome, a maximum of 3 notifications is displayed at any time, even if the other notifications are not related to your site or from OneSignal. This means you can only show 3 categories of notifications to your user, not counting for other notifications that might be displayed at that time.

On Firefox on Windows, many more notifications can be shown at a time (6+).
On Firefox on Mac, and Safari on Mac, only one notification can be shown at a time, even if the other notifications are not related to your site or from OneSignal. Notifications also disappear quickly within 5 seconds and this time is not customizable.

On Chrome/Firefox on Android, multiple notifications can be shown at a time.
If you do not specify web_push_topic , each notification will be replaced by a newer notification. If you do specify web_push_topic, you can choose which notifications will be replaced and which notifications will stack.

When sending a notification using our API, setting a string value for web_push_topic will set the topic for the notification. Any notifications sharing the same topic will replace each other, but any notifications with a different topic won't be replaced.

So suppose you send 4 notifications:

Notification "Open house at 1234 Street at 3 PM this Saturday" with topic 'open-houses'.

Notification "Open house at 1234 Street changed to 4 PM this Saturday" with topic 'open-houses'.

Notification "20 new houses match your criteria in the Seattle, WA" with topic 'general-updates'.

Notification "Find an agent in your area" with topic 'promotional'.
The sequence of notifications observed will be:

Notification #1 shows.

Notification #2 replaces #1 (even if docked in Mac OS X's notification tray).

Notification #3 is shown separately (and if docked in Mac OS X's notification tray, it will use a separate entry).

Notification #4 is also shown separately.

In the end, when the subscriber checks his unread notifications, he will see three total notifications.

Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: Indeed this is an undocumented parameter, but I suspect that by default notifications without topics are automatically replaced by the new one. Maybe this is a bug on their side, but adding this option solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the option `web_push_topic` to your http request.
Every notifications under the same `web_push_topic` will replace the previous one